# Firebase Realtime database Rules Groups with shared data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I need to create a system where there are many groups.

- The group can have multiple users.
- The users can be part of multiple groups.
- The users can have different permissions: read other members data, write other members data, change other members permissions
- All member can read data only from the members of the group, only if they have the read other data permission (Groups/$group_id/Members/uid/canReadOthersData = true).
- Every user it's already storing own data inside UserData path

I have written the following rules, but my problem is that i can't give Group member permissions to read other users data with the or ending part:

> root.child('Group').child($group_id).child('Members').hasChild(auth.uid)

simply because it can't work with $group_id .

I did not found any function that give me the possibility to check if there is a uid inside Groups from the UserData group.
My constraint is that i already have UserData part and i can't change it, because already populated, but i need to define a Group parts around it.
Should i structure this in an other way? Like having an other path that it's defining for every user, the groups that it may be in?

```js
{
  "rules": {

    "Groups": {
      "$group_id": {

        ".read": "data.child('Members').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "data.child(auth.uid).child('canChangeRegistry').val() == true",
        "Members": {
          ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()",
          ".write": "data.child(auth.uid).child('canChangeRegistry').val() == true",
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()",
            ".write": "auth.uid === $uid || data.child('canChangeRegistry').val() == true"
          }
        }
      }
    },

    "UserData": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid || root.child('Groups').child($group_id).child('Members').hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid "
      }
    },

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have the rules search through all groups for a membership match, as that wouldn't scale.

The only option I see is to store an additional list for each user with all other users that they share a group with, and then update that whenever you add users to groups and remove them.

With such a list in place, the lookup in security rules only depends on `auth.uid` and `$uid`, so can be something like:

```
root.child('UserBuddies').child(auth.uid).hasChild($uid)
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask you please what read/write permission would you use for UserBuddies?  Like UserData or something? This would not be easy to manage in case the user is kicked out of the group by the admin

Comment: Yeah, the security rules for such a node are typically rather complex - unless you do the fanout in a Cloud Function.